Extension description text in editor is always black. Need to change to work with a dark editor background
While customizing my theme using workbench.colorCustomizations, I have run into an issue with the text on extension decriptions in editor. When I select an extension, the heading, tabs, and text to the right all use the custom colors. However, the text in description and change log is always black. Since I am using a black background for editor, I have to select the text to read it.
So far, I have been unable to identity the property to change the text.
I have commented the entire workbench.colorCustomizations section with no change.
A new profile with zero customizations does not have the issue.
Update: In the screenshot, the red text changes and I change the settings. The black text does not. This is the same for any extension I click.
screenshot
Update #2: As a test, I created a new profile and copied workbench.colorCustomizations. The new profile does not have the issue, so I am looking at a different settings it seems.

panelTitle is the one which is changing color of labels of Details, features, changelog in extensions panel . Let me know if this is what you looking for.
Modifications in settings.json :
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
"editorGroupHeader.foreground": "#f40808",  
"textLink.foreground": "#f40808",          
"editor.foreground": "#f40808",             
"panelTitle.inactiveForeground": "#f40808",
"panelTitle.activeForeground":"#f40808"

}
and got this result :



You can refer to this for further information :
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Thanks. Unfortunately, that did not change the text giving me a problem. I am new here and will attach a screen shot when I figure out how.

Sure. I saw you added a screenshot just now. Can you please also mention the text u want to change color. I mean you want monokai night theme header text to be changed in the screenshot you attached ?

The black text in the screenshot I attached is the problem, which I just solved. I added fonts to editor.fontFamily. Once I set it to default, everything works as desired.

It seems the problem was adding fonts editor.fontFamily. I had a typo. Lucida Console was not surrounded with quotes.
bad: "editor.fontFamily": "Cambria, 'Cascadia Code', 'Lucida Console, Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
good: "editor.fontFamily": "Cambria, 'Cascadia Code', 'Lucida Console', Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
